# Which permissions scopes are needed for the Journey Builder API Contact Exit Request endpoint?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contact, remove

I'm using the [contactexit endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/contactExitRequest.htm) with an access token generated by the server-to-server integration with the following scopes:

```
{
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "client_id": "1is1x5q1cdxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "client_secret": "zj3d2bxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "scope": "journeys_read"
}
```

However, I am getting 403 for this response which is leading me to believe I don't have the correct scopes. I am able to use the contactExit/status endpoint.

According to the [endpoint permissions documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/rest-permissions-and-scopes.htm), I should be OK using the journeys_read scope.

Would appreciate any help! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce support got back to me, there's a hidden scope called journeys_aspr that you need.

Comment: That scope is not hidden, aspr stands for "Activate Stop Pause Resume" which are permissions you can assign to your installed package yourself.